unable to query all subscribers in child BU
I am trying to query _subscribers in Child BU but am unable to find all records in the query results.
for eg:

SELECT SubscriberKey FROM _Subscribers WHERE Status = 'active'

giving only 6 records where as there are approx 500k records in all subscriber's list
I tried the _ListSubscribers also but it gives records for publication list only I have created and not all subscribers.
When I tried ENT._Subscribers then It gave records but those are not present in Child BU.
So is there any way to get All subscribers in child BU or what could be the possible reasons it is not working?

_Subscribers is an ENT. (Enterprise) level entity, meaning it lives in the Parent BU.
The table does not contain a Child BU association (i.e. it does not list Subscribers per Child BU).
In Short:
The problem is that you are looking for something that the data base does not define; You are looking for "Subscribers in Child BU" - the systemic answer is: No Subscriber is ever "in a child BU". The approximations that exist system side are not retrievable in the (accessible) data base.
So:
-> You would need to define what you consider a sign that "a subscriber belongs to a child BU" (e.g. "I have one automation that fills up a master table per BU, and every one in such a table has that Child BU association") and go from there.
Longer:
Subscribers in the Marketing Cloud lingo are a fixed term. One meaningless but accurate definition would be:
A Subscriber is an entry on "All Subscribers List".
(== a visualization of ENT.subscribers with some added data)
This means: If Subscribers are entries on an ENT. level table, by extension, a Subscriber also is an ENT. level entity.
Special cases aside (you note one), the only way to query all Subscribers is using ENT._Subscribers. -> the system works as designed.
==
Details
One Subscriber could plausibly be associated to MANY BUs - meaning the association would typically not be handled in a table where every Subscriber is listed only once. No accessible Data View exists however that would handle this. -> you'd have to define and build your own infrastructure to query.
The Email Studio "Subscriber Filters" feature that only shows Subscribers when accessing the All Subscribers List from a given BU is a pure UI filter, and has no effect on the visible data base. Such filters change nothing about the above points.
Meaning you won't find any trace of "child BU association" in the _Subscribers table, and in whatever way the Marketing Cloud handles this filter in the backend is not visible to us users.
